# Apollo-codegen skip/ignore some queries while generating flowtype

Tags: graphql, apollo

I want to use apollo-codegen to generate flow types for my queries

```
apollo-codegen generate ./src/**/*.js ...
```

but i have some dynamically created queries like in this dummy example:

```
gql`
    query ${animalName} { 
         animal(name: ${animalName} ){
          id
         }
    }
`
```

This queries are causing apollo-codegen parse errors and are not passing validation. 
Is there a way to skip flow types generation for this queries 
or maybe to ignore files that contains this queries?

---

I am aware of
https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/5-benefits-of-static-graphql-queries-b7fa90b0b69a

Comment: You can add parameters to your query so you don't need to use dynamic queries, otherwise I don't know if you wanna keep dynamic queries absolutely

Comment: Yes that would be perfect, but above example is just a dummy example - I can't change my queries for some other reasons.  So if thats possible I want to skip this queries for now.